# Como puedo manejar los colores de un grafico de amcharts?

Tags: javascript, vscode, amcharts

Hice un gráfico usando amcharts. Les muestro masomenos de que se trata
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si hago click en un nodo, los subnodos se esconden:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de controlar los colores de los nodos. Por ejemplo si en el json recibo un nodo con el valor "Off", el nodo se ponga en color rojo, si es "On" que sea verde.

Les dejo un fragmento del codigo (recorté el json para que me deje pegarlo):

```js
            am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
            var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedTree);
            var networkSeries = chart.series.push(new am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedSeries())

            networkSeries.data = [{
                name: 'Flora',
                fixed: true,
                x: am4core.percent(20),
                y: am4core.percent(50),
                children: [{
                    name: 'Black Tea', value: 1
                }, {
                    name: 'Floral',
                    children: [{
                        name: 'Chamomile', value: 1
                    }, {
                        name: 'Rose', value: 1
                    }, {
                        name: 'Jasmine', value: 1
                    }]
            
            }];
            networkSeries.dataFields.linkWith = "linkWith";
            networkSeries.dataFields.name = "name";
            networkSeries.dataFields.id = "name";
            networkSeries.dataFields.value = "value";
            networkSeries.dataFields.children = "children";
            networkSeries.dataFields.fixed = "fixed";
            networkSeries.nodes.template.propertyFields.x = "x";
            networkSeries.nodes.template.propertyFields.y = "y";
            networkSeries.nodes.template.tooltipText = "{name}";
            networkSeries.nodes.template.fillOpacity = 1;
            networkSeries.nodes.template.label.text = "{name}"
            networkSeries.fontSize = 8;
            networkSeries.maxLevels = 3;
            networkSeries.nodes.template.label.hideOversized = true;
            networkSeries.nodes.template.label.truncate = true;
```

Muchas gracias por ayudar